# How do I print the sum outside the loop ? I think there's some mistake in deceleration of global and local variable

Tags: c++, loops, global-variables, cout, local-variables

When I put the 6th last line (cout << "rank : " << sum + 1 << endl;) outside the loop it says that sum was not declared in this scope.
The code is right below :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace::std;

int main() {

string input;
cout << "Don't enter repetitive alphabet word \n" << "Enter a word : ";
getline(cin, input);

vector<char> myVector(input.begin(), input.end());
vector<char> myVector2(input.begin(), input.end());

sort(myVector2.begin(), myVector2.end());

if(myVector2 == myVector){
    cout << "rank : 1";
}

else{
    for (int i = 0; i < myVector2.size(); i++){
        //cout << myVector2[i]; 
    }

    cout << endl;

    int q = 0, value = 1, w = 1;
    while(q < myVector.size()){
        int k = 0, temp = 0, sum, value = 1, w = 1;
        while(k < myVector2.size()){
            while(myVector2[k] != myVector[q] && k < myVector2.size()){
                while(w < myVector2.size()){
                    value = value * w ;
                    w++;
                }
                k++;
            }
            temp = value * (k);

            break;
        }
        sum = sum + temp;

        myVector2.erase(myVector2.begin()+k);
    /*  for(int j = 0; j < myVector2.size(); j++){
            cout << myVector2[j];
        }*/

        cout << "rank : " << sum + 1 << endl;
        q++;
    }

}
}
```

How do I print the 6th last line : cout << "rank : " << sum + 1 << endl;
outside the loop? And please also explain the reason

Comment: The problem is that your `sum` is declared within the loop. Move the declaration up.

Comment: Define the variable `sum` outside the loop as well?

Comment: Also, the variable `sum` is not initialized before you use it, so you have *undefined behavior* when you do `sum + temp`.

Comment: Thanks #alexeykuzmin0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ each time a curly braces is open, a new scope is created and when closed, it's destroyed. Each scope has access to other scopes as long as they are not destroyed.

Your **sum** is declared within a scope in the first **while** loop. So when the **while** loop is closed, the scope is destroyed, which results your declaration of **sum** to be nullified/destroyed.

You must declare **sum** before your loop and you probably want to initialize it.

```
int q = 0, value = 1, w = 1, sum = 0;
while( ... ) {
    ...
}
```